# Populating List View of Objects dynamically in Android

Tags: android, listview, search, android-arrayadapter, textwatcher

I've looked up a few tutorials online but decided the following was the best approach.

My Activity only consists of a text field (`editText`) and a list view (`roomlv`)

- **CODE**

The objects contained in the list are `RoomCell` objects

My Class has the following variables

```
public class RoomsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview2;
    RoomCell[] roomcells = {rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, rc5, rc6, rc7, rc8, rc9}; 
    //where rc1, rc2, ... are predefined objects
    RoomCell[] finalcells = roomcells;
    RoomListAdapter rla;
```

My onCreate method looks like this:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rooms);

        listview2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.roomlv);
        listview2.setClickable(true);
        listview2.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick2);

        EditText filterText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

        rla = new RoomListAdapter(this, finalcells);
        listview2.setAdapter(rla);

    }
```

where my TextWatcher works like this:

```
private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        if(s.length()==0){

            finalcells = roomcells;
            rla.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }else{

            finalcells = filterList(roomcells, s);
            rla.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
};
```

where the other 2 override methods are omitted for convenience here.

The `filterList()` method returns the filtered array (this, I believe is working fine but I will paste the code if asked for)

And finally the `OnClick` code is here:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick2 = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        GlobVar.roomtitle = finalcells[position].name;
        GlobVar.roomsize = finalcells[position].size;

        Intent i = new Intent(RoomsActivity.this, TheRoomActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

where 2 global variables are assigned specific values to the clicked cells.

- **PROBLEM**

Editing the text field makes no difference whatsoever, and clicking on a cell crashes my program?

I've looked over my code countless times and cannot locate any mistakes.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call:

```
rla = new RoomListAdapter(RoomsActivity.this, finalcells);
listview2.setAdapter(rla);
```

before calling:

```
rla.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

inside your `onTextChanged` method as it will have new filtered objects each time you type into your `EditText`

Comment: That makes sense, what do I replace `this` with, in the RoomListAdapter constructor method

Comment: Replace the `this` with `RoomsActivity.this`, I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmm... this didn't seem to make any difference. Is it possible that I need to add the line `listview2.setAdapter(rla)` again?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that, sorry, yes, you need to set the adapter again.